# PowerShell write integer to file after x number of tabs

Tags: powershell, tabs

I'm sure this is ridiculously easy, but I'm a noob and trying to learn PowerShell.

I want to write an integer to each line of a tab delimited file, i.e. each line has 20 tabs; put a 1 after the nth tab.

No need to overwrite what's already there because in the current scenario there isn't anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If there is a header line then just import the file as a CSV, run it through a `ForEach-Object` loop and set that column to the integer that you want, then export the CSV again.

```
Import-CSV $File -Delimiter "`t" | ForEach{$_.ColumnName = $Integer} | Export-CSV $File -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInfo
```

If there is no header you could do the same thing and define your own headers. Except you would use `ConvertTo-CSV` instead of `Export-CSV` and then use `Select` to skip the header row, and use `Set-Content` to write the file. For my example I set the 7th column to `$Integer`.

```
$Headers = 1..20|ForEach{"Col$_"}
Import-CSV $File -Delimiter "`t" -Header $Headers | ForEach{$_.Col7 = $Integer} | ConvertTo-CSV -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInfo | Select -Skip 1 | Set-Content $File
```